# WindowsApps loads Python install instead of user's installed Python

Tags: python, vba, path

As a result of corporate policy users can't edit their paths, cannot change environment variables.

I figured out via VBA to alter the USER paths.

There's one issue. All the installations have, in the SYSTEM environment variables:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

The PATH of a script session will take the SYSTEM paths and append the USER paths to it.  Pretty normal Windows behavior.

The issue I run into after setting paths is the ORDER causes issues.  WindowsApps has Python as an installation package, so if it comes first in the PATH statement, on some PCs it tries to load the Python install, rather than the user's installed Python.

I have developer rights so I have control of my laptop but my end users do not. If there wasn't a company lockdown, I'd have users remove the WindowsApps from their SYSTEM PATH.

The normal full directory paths:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\;
%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Library;
%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Scripts\;
```

The code:

```vb
Sub RunPythonScript()

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExePath, PythonScript As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
      
    Dim WaitOnReturn As Boolean
    Dim WindowStyle As Integer

    WindowStyle = 1
    WaitOnReturn = True

' find the Python Path in the workbook
    PythonPath_Row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Columns(1).Find(What:="Python Path", LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    PythonPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(PythonPath_Row, 1)

' set only the User environment settings since no admin permission required
    Set colUserEnvVars = objShell.Environment("User")

' save the original PATH
    originalPATH = colUserEnvVars.Item("Path")

' add the needed Python directories to the PATH
    colUserEnvVars.Item("PATH") = PythonPath & ";" & PythonPath & "Library" & ";" & PythonPath & "Library\bin" & ";" & PythonPath & "Scripts" & ";" & colUserEnvVars.Item("Path")

    PythonScript = """" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyScript.py" & """"

    PythonEXE = PythonPath & "python.exe"

' run Python script
    objShell.Run PythonEXE & " " & PythonScript, WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn

' put path back to normal
    colUserEnvVars.Item("PATH") = originalPATH

End Sub
```

I am explicitly calling Python from it's installation directory.
I step through the VBA code and verify the command line passed to the shell.
I opened a CMD prompt after setting the path and it's all correctly modified.

Why are some PCs opening Python from WindowsApps?

Comment: I am afraid that everything done on `objShell.Environment("User")` is useless. Since you supply the path of the exe file from the installation folder, anything you tried before is not used in any way. Instead of you I would previously check what `Debug.Print PythonEXE` returns in `Immediate Window`, just before the line `objShell.Run PythonEXE & " " & PythonScript, WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn`. If you use the same workbook the returned path may not be the correct one. You can also check if the respective path exists using `Debug.print Dir(PythonScript)`. Does it return the necessary path?

Comment: Hmm I open up a CMD prompt while stepping through the code and see the path is correctly appended by the VBA code.  When it finishes, I open another CMD prompt and the path is back to normal.  So it is getting modified.  Let me try those commands you posted and see what happens - I was trying to figure out a good way to debug everything so thank you very much!

Comment: What I wanted to emphasize was not the fact that the `colUserEnvVars.Item("PATH")` is not correctly filled. I only suggested that this operation is useless, **since you supply the real necessary path**. I think the problem stays in the path collected from the workbook. Please, try what I suggested above and see what you can find. Of course, it is only a supposition...

Comment: Yeah I think I have to use someone else's computer as the directories came out as expected in the immediate window, and the code works fine on my laptop.  So I need to find one of these problematic PCs and do the troubleshooting there...

Comment: Of course! My supposition was about exactly such a possibility... The exe application can be installed on a different path. If necessary, I can post a function able to return the path of any application which open a specific extension as default. Extracted from Registry. In this way, your code can use it, extracted from the computer where the code runs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next function to obtain the installation path of any (installed) application which open a specific extension (**as default**):

```
Private Function GetExePath(ext As String) As String
    Dim strAppl As String, strPathExe As String, strExeFile As String
    Dim WSHShell As Object

    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    strAppl = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & ext & "\") & _
                                                                                  "\shell\open\command\")
    If err.Number <> 0 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        GetExePath = ""
        MsgBox "No program installed for extension """ & ext & """"
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    strExeFile = Split(strAppl, """ """)(0)
    strExeFile = Right(strExeFile, Len(strExeFile) - 1)
    GetExePath = strExeFile
End Function
```

You can test it in the next way:

```
Private Sub testGetExeP()
   Debug.Print GetExePath(".xls")
   Debug.Print GetExePath(".pdf")
   Debug.Print GetExePath(".py")
End Sub
```

Please, try comparing the path from the used workbook with the returned exe path. Firstly, to check if my supposition (from the above comment) is confirmed and secondly to use the function instead of the path extracted from any workbook.

Comment: I will give this a shot - it makes more sense anyhow to find the registered Python installed on the system to use (I'm not sure if anyone else (non developer) can read the registry but it's worth a shot).  I still have to add paths or NumPy will error out, but getting them from the registry makes it easier on users.  Much appreciated!